# DRF Got AttributeError in raw sql query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a raw sql command from my django code and I keep getting an error when trying to reach it via Postman. I'm not sure where the problem is.

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `profile_id` on serializer `AllDataSerializer`

**Code**
**Serializer.py**

```
class AllDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = AllData
    fields = [
        'id',
        'profile_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'tweet_text'
    ]
```

**Views.py**

```
class AllData(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

def get(self, profile_id=None):

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT authapi_user.id AS profile_id, authapi_user.first_name, authapi_user.last_name, authapi_tweet.tweet_text FROM authapi_tweet INNER JOIN authapi_user ON authapi_user.id = authapi_tweet.author_id;")
        table = cursor.fetchone()
        data = AllDataSerializer(table).data
        return Response(data)
```

**Models.py**

```
class AllData(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tweet_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Can you test your cursor execution and ```AllDataSerializer``` usage via ```python manage.py shell```? If all is fine then I believe that problem with ```IsOwnerOrReadOnly``` permission class.

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: does the variable contain **`profile_id`** attribute?